# how to display page name as Navigationbar title iOS PageRenderer

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am working on Xamarin.Forms. In iOS `PageRenderer` I need to get page name which is being opened to set that name on `UINavigationbar`. I tried it like below

```
public class ContentPageRenderer : PageRenderer
    {
        string pageName = string.Empty, pageName2 = string.Empty;
        public new ContentPage Element
        {
            get { return (ContentPage)base.Element; }
        }
        protected override void OnElementChanged(VisualElementChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);  
            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                var att = new UITextAttributes();
                att.Font = UIFont.FromName("Space Age", 24);
                UINavigationBar.Appearance.SetTitleTextAttributes(att);
                pageName = e.GetType().Name;
                pageName2 = App.Current.MainPage.Title.ToString();
            }
        }
        public override void ViewWillAppear(bool animated)
        {
            base.ViewWillAppear(animated);

            if (NavigationController == null)
                return;
            var navigationItem = NavigationController.TopViewController.NavigationItem;
            UIBarButtonItem backButton = new UIBarButtonItem();
            backButton.Title = "back"; //Your BackBurron Title here
            NavigationController.NavigationBar.TopItem.BackBarButtonItem = backButton;

            //setting title
            navigationItem.Title = "test Title"  //pageName;
        }
    }
```

Here in the code `pageName` & `pageName2` I am not getting current page to set that value as title of `UINavigationbar`

When I tried setting title in PCL project's Homework page, It is getting set on **Tabs text** on bottom not `Navigatoinbar` title

Below HomeWork.xaml.cs page

```
public Homework ()
{
    InitializeComponent ();
    Title = "Homework";
}
```

This is Homework.xaml page

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Shared:CToolbarPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             Title="Diary"  
             Icon="dairy"
             xmlns:Shared="clr-namespace:edTheSIS.Shared"                        
             x:Class="edTheSIS.Pages.Homework">

    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
            <Shared:MainListView></Shared:MainListView>
        </ContentPage.BindingContext>
    <ListView Margin="0,0,0,0" 
              SeparatorVisibility="Default"    
    </ListView>
</Shared:CToolbarPage>
```

See below screenshot for more information

[image]

Below how Title setting on Tab's text

[image]

Comment: Why do this through a custom renderer? Just set the Title property of the page you're navigating to. This is the page where you want to show the title. No renderers needed.

Comment: Page Title directly setting on Tab text on bottom as I wrote in my question

Comment: Not the tab, the page. Can you show what you did there?

Comment: Please look at my updated question. Where I have added `Homework.xaml` & 1 screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I figured it out how to set page name as title. In Our TabbedPage(PCL) need to add some code

```
 this.CurrentPageChanged += CurrentPageHasChanged;     

 protected void CurrentPageHasChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {           
   this.Title = this.CurrentPage.Title;
 }
```

However along with Navigation bar Title it is changing Tab text too.